# Unity3D: Terrain issue on Android when using [Stripping Level]

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the Stripping Level to optimize the mobile app size.
But when I turn ON the Stripping Level (Strip Assemblies / Strip Bytecode / Use micro mscorelib), I got nothing to show the terrain in my Android app.

I checked the official documentation but there's no explanation about the Stripping Level that affect the terrain show.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally using the Unity terrain on mobile is a big no no, since it uses a lot of resources. they have done some modifications since last i checked when it wasn't supported at all.
Personally i would export the terrain to multiple 3D objects so occlusion culling will help with the performance.
which in turn will be supported by all devices/platforms.

> Rendering terrain is quite expensive, so terrain engine is not very practical on lower-end mobile devices.

according to: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Terrains.html ( at the end )

i guess the develops figured when stripping to mobile you want it lightweight and fast which mobile terrain is not. they might change it, but a good practice would be to not use the terrain engine on mobile.

Comment: Thanks very much!  So should I post a mail to the Official Unity?

Comment: you could, but they are aware of it, since its a highly talking about subject on their forums, which their employees monitor daily.